# all operator cause ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I get an error message when I execute follow statement:

```
UPDATE dept d 
SET city = ALL (SELECT city FROM locations l 
                WHERE d.location_id = l.location_id);
```

When I get rid of ALL operator, success.

```
UPDATE dept d 
SET city = (SELECT city FROM locations l 
            WHERE d.location_id = l.location_id);
```

Can someone tell me what the "ALL" operator is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALL` reserved word is for suqueries in select statements but not in UPDATE statement.

Quoting [Subqueries with ALL Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/all-subqueries.html):

> The word ALL, which must follow a comparison operator, means “return
>   TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for ALL of the values in the column
>   that the subquery returns.”

That means that `=` sign should be use as a comparation, not as assignation.

If you expect that subquery resturns more than one row you can limit results with max or rownun:

```
UPDATE dept d 
SET city = (SELECT max( city ) FROM locations l 
            WHERE d.location_id = l.location_id);
```